# DRF Serializer handling generated field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a Django model that has two required fields - **name** and a **slug**. 
The **slug** could be passed in during the POST request or otherwise can be generated from **name**. I then have a model Serializer with both **slug** and **name** fields. If the slug is not passed in it throws an error that slug is a required field. However, I want to make it so that if slug is not passed in, I generate it from the name that is always passed in. Is there a way to do this gracefully in Serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: add `required=False` to the `slug` serializer field and then in your serializer's `create` method default the slug field to the generated value, like so:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    slug = serializers.SlugField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def create(self, data):
        if not data.get('slug'):
            data['slug'] = generate_slug_from_name(data.get('name'))
        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).create(data)
```